Conjugate Representation is equivalent to Dual Representation
I was trying to solve the following problem, but I don't know under what "formal" hypothesis it holds, and what is really being asked:
Let $D: G \to Aut(V)$ be a linear unitary G-representation. So the induced conjugate representation $\overline{D}$ is equivalent to the induced dual representation $D^*$.
I was wondering first for V finite-dimensional (with some inner-product fixed), so the dual-topological is the same as the dual-algebraic.
And my definitions are:
The conjugate representation: $\overline{D}: G \to Aut(\overline{V})$ s.t. given $g \in G$, $\overline{D}(g) := \overline{D(g)}$;
The dual representation: $D^*: G \to Aut(V^*)$ s.t. given $g \in G$ and given a linear functional $\phi$, $D(g) \phi := \phi \circ D(g^{-1})$;
Unitary means D is an isometry, i.e., for all $g \in G$, and for all $u,v \in V$, $\langle u , v \rangle = \langle D(g)u, D(g)v \rangle$;
Finally, my definition for two representations to be equivalent is: $D_1,D_2: G \to Aut(V)$ are equivalent if exists some  $S \in Aut(V)$, such that $D_1 = SD_2 S^{-1}$.
But in the context of the question, this definition doesn't make sense; the representations act in distinct vector spaces.
I know that $\overline{V} \simeq V^*$ by $ v \in \overline{V} \mapsto \langle v , \cdot \rangle \in V^*$.
I think I have to show that, under this linear isomorphism, the two representations are equivalent, but I have no clue how to proceed in that way.
Thanks.


Write the isomorphism $\overline{V} \simeq V^\ast$ by $S$. Calculate what $S^{-1}D^\ast(g)S\overline{v}$ is for $\overline{v} \in \overline{V}$ and $g \in G$. Also use the fact that $D(g^{-1}) = D(g)^\ast$. It’s sort of immediate from that. The confusion is mainly just notational.

Get it. Thanks!
